# VMS directory issue

Tags: directory-structure, openvms

I'm not that familiar to VMS directory structure.So, I have an application installed on VMS. I am getting an error message when starting the application...I know it's just a directory path issue. The application is installed on `DKA0:[TEST.ONE]` using user SYSTEM and the home directory of the user SYSTEM is `SYS$SYSROOT:[SYSMGR]`. Now, when I start the application I got the following:

```
**%DCL-W-DIRECT, invalid directory syntax - check brackets and other delimiters \SYS$SYSROOT:[SYSMGRDKA0\**
```

Notice the `SYSMGRDKA0\` .

Now, my question is..is there a way to change the directory to `DKA0:[TEST.ONE]` from `SYS$SYSROOT:[SYSMGR]` ? I tried the following:

```
$ set def SYS$SYSROOT:[SYSMGR]DKA0:[TEST.ONE]
%DCL-W-PARMDEL, invalid parameter delimiter - check use of special characters
 \:\
```

Thanks in advance!
Joie

Comment: You could try setting the default to the application's directory: `$ set default DKA0:[TEST.ONE]`. Or, assuming that you are using system root `0`, try `$ set default Sys$SysDevice:[SYS0.SYSMGR]`. It isn't clear what the application is doing that is causing the problem, but it may be having trouble with the rooted directory or search path.

Comment: @HABO Hi Habo, Thanks for the reply. Yes, the application has configuration file in which there's a variable  for the installation directory of the application. This variable has already been set to DKA0:[TEST.ONE] . But for some reason, when I start the application it is trying to access the path [SYSMGRDKA0, I don't know if this path is vlaid or not. As you can see here...%DCL-W-DIRECT, invalid directory syntax - check brackets and other delimiters . 
\SYS$SYSROOT:[SYSMGRDKA0\

Comment: @HABO , Hi HABO, this is what I found. I traced the startup script of the application. It looks like the SYS$SYSROOT:[SYSMGR] is concatenated with DKA0:[TEST.ONE] so as a result the working directory is SYS$SYSROOT:[SYSMGRDKA0:[TEST.ONE]] . Is this valid ? Thank you in advance?

Comment: That's not valid. The simple view is `Device:[Dir.SubDir.SubSubDir]`. (It is complicated by the fact that `Sys$SysRoot` is a logical name that is a search list, i.e. has more than one translation.) Can you edit your question to include the "startup script" which is, I assume, a DCL command procedure? That may provide a clue as to _why_ it is combining paths.

Comment: @HABO, Hi Habo I managed to make it work. IN the startup script I just remove the concatenation of systemroot directory so that the working directory will be only DKA0:[TEST.ONE]..Thanks again!

Comment: Joie Tamayo, you need to create an answer and mark that as valid. Adding just comments and leaving the question unanswered is not considered OK on SO.

Answer (score 1):

@HABO, Hi Habo I managed to make it work. IN the startup script I just remove the concatenation of systemroot directory so that the working directory will be only DKA0:[TEST.ONE]..Thanks again!